# How to select max date over the year function

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I am trying to select the max date over the year, but it is not working. Any ideas on what to do?

```
SELECT a.tkinit [TK ID],
   YEAR(a.tkeffdate) [Rate Year],
   max(a.tkeffdate) [Max Date],
   tkrt03 [Standard Rate]

FROM stageElite.dbo.timerate a
join stageElite.dbo.timekeep b ON b.tkinit = a.tkinit 

WHERE a.tkinit = '02672'
and tkeffdate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '12-31-2014'


GROUP BY a.tkinit,
 tkrt03,
 a.tkeffdate
```

Comment: You can't have different date formats when using BETWEEN, verify which one is correct and then use that format for both dates (or use `YEAR(tkeffdate) = 2014`). In your GROUP BY remove `a.tkeffdate` and it is pointless to have YEAR in the select list since everything is from the same year. Same thing for `a.tkinit` that is also a single value

Comment: You need to group by `YEAR(a.tkeffdate)` not `a.tkeffdate`, since you want the rows to roll-up by year..  You will also need to decide what to do with your rate column, since that can vary and won't group into a single yearly row either.  Maybe you want multiple rows per year/rate (currently you would get that), but it doesn't read like you do. (PS. Remove the `sql server` or `mysql` tag and leave only the one you are using, and add expected results to the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you only want it by year and not rolled up by calendar date. For SQL server you can try this.

```
SELECT
   …
   MaxDate = MAX(a.tkeffdate) OVER (PARTITION BY  a.tkinit, YEAR(a.tkeffdate)))
   …
```

Or you could modify the query above to group by the year instead of date-->

```
GROUP BY a.tkinit,
 tkrt03,
 YEAR(a.tkeffdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want only one row and all the columns.  Use `ORDER BY` and `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) tr.tkinit as [TK ID],
       YEAR(tr.tkeffdate) as [Rate Year],
       a.tkeffdate as [Max Date],
       tkrt03 as [Standard Rate]
FROM stageElite.dbo.timerate tr JOIN
     stageElite.dbo.timekeep tk
     ON tk.tkinit = tr.tkinit 
WHERE tr.tkinit = '02672' AND
      tr.tkeffdate >= '2014-01-01' AND
      tr.tkeffdate < '2015-01-01'
ORDER tr.tkeffdate DESC;
```

Note that I also fixed your date comparisons and table aliases.